# What percent of doctors are qualified to do surgeries in US?

Tags: statistics, united-states

I am looking for a rough estimation of how many doctors are qualified to do surgeries. Google searching with this prompt and variations of it, have found me no reliable sources. The only one I could find was [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-percentage-of-physicians-are-surgeons) which refers AAMC.org for specific answer of physicians. However, I couldn't find this on the site itself when I searched it there.

Comment: What you need is the AMA Physician Masterfile. Unfortunately, it's not free.